# Vies VAT Validator checkout WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

does anyone know this plugin for VAT validation? https://wordpress.org/plugins/vies-validator/

Here is the explanation of the library used: https://github.com/pH-7/eu-vat-validator

It works very well, also because in my case I already have the VAT number as a field, and therefore, since it allows you to assign the ID to the panel of your existing field, it validates it.

However, I would like to exclude Italy from validation, inside the plugin I see the 3 functions that validate the VAT number, but I can't understand how to exclude the country I want.

```
/**
 * Validate the VAT Number
 *
 * @since    1.0.0
 */
public function vies_validator_validate_vat() {
    $enable_vat = get_option($this->option_name . '_add_vat_field');
    if ($enable_vat && $enable_vat == 1) {
        $vat_id = 'vies_billing_vat';
    }
    else {
        $vat_id = get_option($this->option_name . '_vat_id');
    }

    if ($vat_id && !empty(trim($vat_id))) {
        $this->vies_validator_validate_vat_field($vat_id);
    }
}

/**
 * Check a VAT Number via API
 *
 * @since    1.0.0
 */
protected function vatCheck($vat_number) {
    $country = substr($vat_number, 0, 2);
    try {
        $oVatValidator = new Validator(new Europa, $vat_number, $country);
        return $oVatValidator->check();
        }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Validates vat number
 *
 * @since    1.0.0
 */
protected function vies_validator_validate_vat_field($vat_id) {
        if(isset($_POST[$vat_id]) && !empty($_POST[$vat_id])) {
            $vat_number = $_POST[$vat_id];
            if (! $this->vatCheck($vat_number)) {
                wc_add_notice(__(get_option('vies_validator_message'), 'vies-validator'), 'error');
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Only the functions are protected and public and I don't understand how to call a hook to make the function run in WordPress functions.php.

Here, I see the hooks being logged and there is the WooCommerce checkout hook.

```
/**
 * Register all of the hooks related to the public-facing 
functionality
 * of the plugin.
 *
 * @since    1.0.0
 * @access   private
 */
private function define_public_hooks() {

    $plugin_public = new Vies_Validator_Public( $this->get_plugin_name(), $this->get_version() );

    $this->loader->add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', $plugin_public, 'enqueue_styles' );
    $this->loader->add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', $plugin_public, 'enqueue_scripts' );

    if (get_option('vies_validator_add_vat_field') == '1') {
        $this->loader->add_filter('woocommerce_billing_fields', $plugin_public, 'vies_validator_add_vat_field', 10, 1);

        $this->loader->add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_address_formatted_address', $plugin_public, 'vies_my_account_my_address_formatted_address', 10, 3 );

        $this->loader->add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_formatted_billing_address', $plugin_public, 'vies_add_vat_formatted_billing_address', 10, 2 );

        $this->loader->add_filter( 'woocommerce_formatted_address_replacements', $plugin_public, 'vies_formatted_address_replacements', 10, 2 );

        $this->loader->add_filter( 'woocommerce_customer_meta_fields', $plugin_public, 'vies_customer_meta_fields' );

        $this->loader->add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_billing_fields', $plugin_public, 'vies_admin_billing_fields' );

        $this->loader->add_filter( 'woocommerce_found_customer_details', $plugin_public, 'vies_found_customer_details' );
    }

    $this->loader->add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', $plugin_public, 'vies_validator_validate_vat');
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the code to accept all Italian VAT numbers then you can just make a small modification to the vat check function:

```
protected function vatCheck($vat_number) {
    $country = substr($vat_number, 0, 2);
    if ($country == 'IT' || $country == 'it') {
       return true;
    } else {
       try {
           $oVatValidator = new Validator(new Europa, $vat_number, $country);
           return $oVatValidator->check();
       }
       catch (Exception $e) {
           return false;
       }
    }
}
```

If you want the code to reject all Italian numbers then use this version:

```
protected function vatCheck($vat_number) {
    $country = substr($vat_number, 0, 2);
    if ($country == 'IT' || $country == 'it') {
       return false;
    } else {
       try {
           $oVatValidator = new Validator(new Europa, $vat_number, $country);
           return $oVatValidator->check();
       }
       catch (Exception $e) {
           return false;
       }
    }
}
```

Good luck. I hope it will work for you. If not then you might find this VAT Validation Add-in that works with directly within Excel and can do bulk VAT validation: https://www.sanocast.dk/vat-validation/
It is fantastic! (I might be a little biased - it is my own creation)